# Getting authentication token when calling a get url from google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-compute-engine

I am trying to connect my compute engine app from app engine using [App Identity](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/appidentity/) feature of Google Cloud.

I am not sure from where do I need to extract accessToken which can be used for authentication. I am getting invalid access token currently, below is the code I am using for getting access token:

```
 URL url = new URL("http://104.197.5.2/MyApp/route?TN=12402735");
 ArrayList < String > scopes = new ArrayList < String > ();
 scopes.add("http://104.197.5.2/MyApp/route?TN=12402735");
 AppIdentityService appIdentity = AppIdentityServiceFactory.getAppIdentityService();

 AppIdentityService.GetAccessTokenResult accessToken = appIdentity.getAccessToken(scopes);

 HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 connection.setDoOutput(true);
 connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
 connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
 connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer  " + accessToken.getAccessToken());

 connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
     connection.getInputStream()));
 String inputLine;
 while ((inputLine = in .readLine()) != null)
     resp.getWriter().println(inputLine); in .close();
```

On the server code ( hosted on compute engine), how should I validate the incoming token ie what should I compare it with

Below is the excerpt of the server log when my get call reaches it

```
2015-04-29 07:12:52+0000 [HTTPChannel,0,98.188.155.163] 
{  
   'host':'104.197.53.229',
   'content-type':'application/json',
   'connection':'Keep-Alive',
   'authorization':'Bearer InvalidToken:http://104.197.5.2/MyApp/route?TN=12402735:2123'
}
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Can you please tell me how you fixed it ?